# Struggling to start a project from scratch

Tags: 6

I am having 6 months of experience in drupal 6. I can able to handle bugs and any new functionality in the existing project.

**But i can't able to move single step ahead in the new project.** I know PHP very well and if i need to start a project from scratch in PHP i can do without any hesitation.

But i can't able to do with drupal :(

> 1. What is the problem with me ?
> 2. What should i need to do to start a project from scratch ?
> 3. What are the things i need to improve ?

Any guidance will help me a lot..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["Drupal learning curve" article](http://nodeone.se/blogg/the-drupal-learning-curve-a-configurators-view) will help you put things in perspective. You can't learn Drupal in a day, but if you learn a little bit every day you'll be a pro soon.
The [buildamodule.com](http://buildamodule.com/) courses are a great learning tool.

If you start with Drupal I also recommend starting on Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds, what Your problem is not in Drupal.

Check the [Done Manifesto](http://www.brepettis.com/blog/2009/3/3/the-cult-of-done-manifesto.html), probably it will help.

And let's move to Drupal 7 :)

Comment: +1 for great article. My prob is not with the requirements. If i have the same i can't able to start even with PHP. My prob is how to start with drupal. In existing project all are created already. My work is  to modify them or to enhance based on the requirements.. So, i have don't have idea on creating "new stuff". That's what my prob here..

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need project requirements.

Then install Drupal which is very easy to do and start reviewing the modules which could provide functionality you are looking for.

Try to come up with very specific project related problems instead of asking philosophical questions.

There is nothig wrong with you, just do it!